# Do Applications run across a network still use User Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

Referring to settings in the application, with Scope "User"

From my understanding, the user settings in a C# WPF program get stored in a localApps folder.

Is this on the server or on the client machine, if running the exe from a network location?

Aka, will the client machine still have its own settings, or will everyone accessing it be using the setting on the server.

Comment: You've specified per user - it will be client end

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the binaries may exist on a remote machine, the execution happens on the local machine and therefore the any application data paths using things like `%APPDATA%` will be referencing the local machine.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldnt find any solid info about it. And cant deploy it to test, as still in development. This has made me happy. :) I assume by extension you are reffering to the setting file.